# A proof of Hölder's inequality and trying to understand this

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, holder-inequality

Let's state the Hölder's inequality in the following way:

\begin{equation*}
|\sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k| \leq (\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p)^{1/p} (\sum_{k=1}^n |y_k|^q)^{1/q}
\end{equation*}

where $1\leq p < \infty$ and $q$ is such that $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Note that this just becomes the Cauchy-Schwarz for $p=1/2=q$

Proof is as follows:

> Consider $y=\log(x)$; x>0.
>
> Since $y$ is a concave function it follows that $$\theta \log a + (1-\theta) \log b \leq \log (\theta a + (1- \theta )b)$$
>   Taking exponentials $a^{\theta}b^{1-\theta} \leq \theta a + (1- \theta )b$.
>
> **Now let $a= \frac{a_i}{A}$ and $b=\frac{b_i}{B}$ where $A= \sum a_i$ and $B= \sum b_i$.
>
>    Plug the new expressions for $a$ and $b$ and sum them from $i=1$ to $n$** we end up with 
>   \begin{equation*}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{\theta}b_i^{1-\theta} \leq (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^{\theta} (\sum_{i=1}^n b_i)^{(1-\theta)}
> \end{equation*}
>   Make the substitution $a_i^{\theta} = |x_i|$, $b_i^{1-\theta} = |y_i|$ and $1-\theta = 1/q$, $\theta = 1/p$ you would end up with Hölder's inequality.

Q: I couldn't understand the part in bold. What is $a_i$? , $b_i$? Are they the basis for the vector space? If so Does Hölder's inequality hold only for vector spaces? And how did you sum up two parts of an inequality from $i=1$ to $n$? Can we do that?

What is reason behind setting $a=\frac{a_i}{A}$ and $b= \frac{b_i}{B}$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_i$ and $b_i$ are just a very cunning change of variable nothing more.

As you can see $a_i=|x_i|^{1/\theta}$ $b_i=|y_i|^{1/(1-\theta)}$

Next $a_i>0$ and $b_i>0$ so $a_i^\theta b_i^{1-\theta} >0$ and transforming 
$$a_i^\theta b_i^{1-\theta} \leq \theta a_i A^{\theta-1} B^{1-\theta}+(1-\theta)b_i A^\theta B^{-\theta}$$ into

$$ \sum_i (a_i^\theta b_i^{1-\theta}) \leq \sum_i (\theta a_i A^{\theta-1} B^{1-\theta}+(1-\theta)b_i A^\theta B^{-\theta})$$

is completely licit.

The inequality is finally obtained noticing that $$\sum_i (\theta a_i A^{\theta-1} B^{1-\theta}+(1-\theta)b_i A^\theta B^{-\theta})=A^\theta B^{1-\theta}$$

Proof is obtained noticing that $|\sum_{k=1}^n x_k y_k| \leq \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| |y_k|$